# FB Graph API fetch insights for Instagram media collection with limit

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

Trying to fetch insights for media collection with these query:

```
<page id>/media?fields=id,media_url,media_type,timestamp,like_count,media_product_type,permalink,comments{like_count},ig_id,comments_count,insights.metric(impressions,engagement,reach,saved)&limit=30
```

In return get only **ONE** record with insights.

**Need insights for collection of last 30 posts**.

When remove `insights.metric(impressions,engagement,reach,saved)` api returns last 30 posts but obviously without insights

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be correct query, media need to be  poster after general API change 2020.
Everything works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).